# How to find cell text with any placement in the cells within a Column?

Tags: excel

I need a formula for the following.

I have two columns A & C containing text and I need to find if the text from the cells in Column A are anywhere in Column C. The result of the search query for the text present in A cells to be listed in Column B

EXAMPLE:
In A2 there is text
I want to be able to list 'True or False' or a number whether that text is anywhere within Column C.

EXAMPLE: The text in A2 does not have to be the exact same cell text as in Column C - but the text should be somewhere in that same order.

```
ie. in A2 the text  is **elephant**
in Column C 
C2 French cat eating = (Answer in B2) No
C3 Black German dog running = (Answer in B3) No
C4 Grey African **elephant** eating grass = (Answer in B4) yes
```

Comment: so the text is always in A2? and jsut the texts you want to search through are in column C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with the the **SEARCH** formula:

i.e in cell B2:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$2,C2))
```

i.e in cell B3:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$2,C3))
```

etc.

See here for more info: https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-specific-text

---

According to the link above, there are many other little tweaks to make the formula perfect for your case. For example if you need *custom text*:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$2,C2)), "Yes!! :)", "No!! :/")
```

If you need *case-sensitivity*, you need to use FIND instead of SEARCH

```
=ISNUMBER(FIND($A$2,C2))
```

See this reference image from https://exceljet.net/

[image]